# Android RX Java 2 disposable

Tags: java, android, rx-java, rx-android

When I used RXJava 1 I always kept track of my subscriptions to execute the unsubscribe in the activity onDestroy. Example: https://medium.com/@scanarch/how-to-leak-memory-with-subscriptions-in-rxjava-ae0ef01ad361

Recently I moved to RXJava 2 and then I looked online for suggestions of how to handle the new disposables.

But I can't find anything, every example that I see just ignore then.

Did RXJava 2 changed it and now I don't need anymore to execute the dispose method from the disposable or I should implement in the same way I was implementing in the RXJava 1 days?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you get a `Disposable` with your subscription, you can as well use `CompositeDisposable`.

If you use some of the subscription methods not returning a `Disposable`, you could as well just use the `takeUntil` or `takeWhile` methods to *dispose* the subscription.